# How can one upload an excel spread sheet with paperclip gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

Can you upload an excel file (`.xls`) to s3 with the `paperclip` gem in rails?

I have searched [their docs](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) and grep'd through their source code for `content_type` and I only see types for images, pdfs and others but nothing for `csv` or `xls`. Also, there seems to be a noticeable absence on any content with examples or guidelines on using paperclip to upload spread sheets. For instance, thoughtbot has a [blog post](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/for-attaching-files-use-paperclip) saying "You can upload anything" so I'd like to believe you can upload an excel spread sheet.

Comment: Please leave a comment if you are going to down vote

Comment: It's pretty simple really. Just follow the docs. Ignore anything image related. For example you will not need to install ImageMagick etc. You will not need to define versions (thumbs etc) for the uploaded file. Everything else should just work for any type of file, including CSV or XLS.

Answer (score 0):

You can using `has_attached_file` and validate with `matches`, for example:

```
has_attached_file :file
validates_attachment_file_name :file, matches: [/\.xls?$/, /\. xlsx?$/, /\.csv?$/]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the same as what you do for other kind of documents.

```
has_attached_file :sheet
validates_attachment :sheet, presence: true,
                      content_type: {
                        content_type: [
                          "application/vnd.ms-excel",
                          "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
                        ]
                      }
```

Or you can also use matches for matching the extension.

```
validates_attachment_file_name :sheet, matches: [/.xls\z/i, /.xlsx\z/i, /.csv\z/i]
```